# upower battery with pending-change and won't start charging

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

I have installed Ubuntu (version 23.04) last week on my laptop (Dell Inspiron N5010), and since then my battery isn't charging.

Previously on Windows it did recognize and charged the battery.

When I run the `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` it founds the battery and says:

```
[...]
present: yes
rechargeable: yes
state: pending-charge
[...]
```

Capacity, voltage, model, serial, power supply, all seem fine.

Things I tried:

- disconnect the battery and put it on again
- disconnect power cable while on BIOS
- updated BIOS from A07 to A15
- changed the "Charge behavior" BIOS settings from Enable to Disable and from Disable to Enable (on A07 and A15 versions)

**UPDATE**:
The `charge_control_end_threshold` and `charge_control_start_threshold` are not available.

Also tried the cctk from Dell to change the `primaryBattChargeCfg`
[image]

Comment: Ubuntu Server 23?

Comment: Ubuntu 23. Not sure why I wrote server, but I have removed it.

Comment: Not an improvement as there is no Ubuntu 23 of any kind.

Comment: What I’m getting wrong? Isn’t there a version 23.04 for Ubuntu that was released a couple of weeks ago?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Yes, there is indeed a recent release of Ubuntu, 23.04. I think it'd be more appropriate if that was noted in the question, as this question may be referenced in the future when there will be more than one release of Ubuntu for 2023 (23.04 and 23.10, as currently planned).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @richbl, will update the question

Comment: I'd suggest that you check the charge thresholds for your laptop battery by going (from the command line) to `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` and running `cat charge_control_start_threshold` and `cat charge_control_end_threshold.` These are the two value limits for charging your battery: below the lower limit your battery will charge, but above that value it won't charge even if plugged into AC power (which would explain the `pending charge` state you noted). Not sure what the latest Ubuntu defaults are, but worth confirmation to remove this as a variable to your issue.

Comment: Hey @richbl, thanks for the reply. Just tried that but don't have the `charge_control_end_threshold` and `charge_control_start_threshold` available here (as shown on the image I posted right now on the question).

I searched other ways and find out about the `cctk` from Dell (my notebook manufacture) and tried the `primaryBattChargeCfg` setting, but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try libsmbios to see if you can change charging threshold and see if the pending-charge is due of threshold.

```
sudo apt-get install smbios-utils
sudo apt install smbios-battery-ctl
```

then try changing threshold modes

```
sudo smbios-battery-ctl --set-charging-mode='standard'
```

There are other modes as well 'adaptive' , 'express', 'custom'

```
sudo smbios-battery-ctl --set-charging-mode='custom'
sudo smbios-battery-ctl --set-custom-charge-interval=95 100
```